# async and await in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In my flutter app, the async function runs at last, but according to the code, it should run after the print start and before the print end.

```
@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   print('start');
   getApiData();
   print('end');
}

void getApiData() async {
   HomePageNetworking homePageNetworking = HomePageNetworking();
   var apiIndiaData = await homePageNetworking.getDataIndia();
   print(apiIndiaData);
}
```

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: `but according to the code, it should run after the print start and before the print end.` Then what is the difference between async functions and normal functions ?

Comment: I want the data which I get from the api to be in a Text() widget, how can I do that, what changes do I need to make in my code to achieve that?

Comment: 1) You can use .then syntax (of async await) and setState to achieve that 2) You can use FutureBuilderWidget to handle these kind of scenarios. If you post your build method also, I can help you use futurebuilder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try that:
Put all of them in an async function and call the function in the initstate.